# how can i wrap an android app as a react native component (complete view)?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a working android native app that i need to call as a view in react native with react-navigation, how can i wrap the android app in a component and call it in the StackNavigator like:

```
const Nav = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginView },
  Player: { screen: PlayerView },
  Android: { screen: AndroidView }, //this should be the android native view
},{
    headerMode: 'none',
});
```

How can i pass a variable to that 'view'?

I tried to follow the docs on react-native github project but i didn't understood exactly what i have to implement in my app because the docs start from the beginning of the android app.

Answer (score 1):

The Integration of already implemented native code is as very simple. Please follow the below steps:

There will be three files namely, view manager, your view file and package file

1) Create a js file from where you will communicate with native code:

```
 var { requireNativeComponent, PropTypes } = require('react-native');

var tosendvalue= {
  name: 'xyz',
  propTypes: {
    value: PropTypes.string
  }
};

module.exports = requireNativeComponent('RCTtest', tosendvalue);
```

2) Native class to communicate: (View manager file)

```
public class TestViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<TestViewDemo>{ 
 public static final String REACT_CLASS = “RCTtest”;
 @Override
 public String getName() {
   return REACT_CLASS;
 }

 // Views are created in the createViewInstance method, the view should  //initialize itself in its default state, any properties will be set 
//via a follow up call to updateView.


   @Override
     protected TestViewDemo createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext 
        themedReactContext) {
       return new TestViewDemo (themedReactContext);
     }
      //we will check the variable that we have send it from javascript file.
     @ReactProp(name = "value")
public void setVauleFunction(TestViewDemo view, @Nullable String value) {
   view.setVauleFunction(value);             
}
```

3) Your native view: (your view class)

```
   public class TestViewDemo extends Activity {
 //your predefined view
 @Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
   super.onCreate(icicle);
   setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
   mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
   mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
   if (path == "") { return; }
   mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
   mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
   mVideoView.requestFocus();
 }

  public void setVauleFunction(value)
 {
  log.e(value)//here you will get your react native value.
 }
    ...
    }
```

4) Now your package file:

```
public class ReactVideoPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
         //added my view manager
   return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(new TestViewManager());
    }
}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: i still don't understand, which packages have i to import and in which file? I just get a lot of errors this way. I have a main activity that set some params and call the view activity.

Comment: In main activity, under get packages insert the name of your package. Don't panic go step by step.

Comment: The native code is not implemented yet, that is the first question, how to integrate it with my react-native application, on the navigator, after that how to pass a variable. I have only the native code and my react-native app separately right now. I followed the guide step by step, creating NativeComm.js in my component folder and in native folder 2 files TestViewManager.java, ReactVideoPackage.java and i modified MainActivity.java as described. Now when i do: import RCTtest from './NativeComm' i get undefined error. From which file should i import the component?